# How to set data in redis hash using ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

Currently I am caching data from active record to redis by doing following:

**redis.rb**

```
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("bookstore", :redis => Redis.new)
```

**authors_helper.rb**

```
def fetch_authors
    authors = $redis.get('authors')
    if authors.nil?
      authors = Author.all.to_json
      $redis.set("authors", authors).to_json
      $redis.expire("authors", 5.hour.to_i)
    end
    JSON.load authors
end
```

So currently I am using basic `set` and `get` to cache and read data from redis.

I want to use `hmset` instead of just `set`. The redis way to to this job is as follows:

(Just an example)

```
HMSET user:1001 name "Mary Jones" password "hidden" email "mjones@example.com"
```

The **authors** table in my app consists of following field: `id` ,`name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

What is the ruby way to use `hmset` so that I can cache `authors` data in a redis hash?

Comment: Why dont you use [Rails.cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can save all authors this way. This is because a hash can store only one value for each key. So `name` and `created_at` cannot be keys, because all authors need to store their own values for these keys, but you can use each key only once.

If you're using Ruby on Rails, using `Rails.cache` is preferred - this way you don't have to worry about the way Rails stores the object in Redis.

However, if you want to use `hmset` for some reason, I believe the best you can do is something like this:

`authors = Author.all.flat_map { |author| [author.id.to_s, author.attributes.to_json] }
$redis.hmset("authors", *authors_data)`

The first line will return something like this:

`['1', '{"name": "Mary Jones", "email": "m@example.com"}', '2', '{"name": "Another name", "email": "e@example.com"']`

`hmset` command does not accept array, but a flat list of attributes, that's why in the 2nd line you need to pass `*authors_data` to the function.

Then, internally it will look like this:

`{
  '1' => '{"name": "Mary Jones", "email": "m@example.com"}',
  '2' => '{"name": "Another name", "email": "e@example.com"'
}`

Later you can do `$redis.hmget("authors", '1')` which will return a String `'{"name": "Mary Jones", "email": "m@example.com"}'`